# How to use SQL Server Integration Services to update production server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a development server (SQL Server 2008) it has database. i.e. `Employee` (database) on it, I have tables,stored procedure and data as well.

And I have another production server (SQL Server 2008) also it has same database i.e. `Employee` (database) on it, I have tables, stored procedure and data as well.

Now my website running from production server.

When I make changes in development server and create one more table, stored procedure and also insert some data, then I want to update my production server so that my changes will go to running website

Make sure i can do it following ways:

1. Using Backup SQL Server (.bak file).
2. Using SQL script with data.
3. Using MDf LDF file.

But I want to do this by using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS).

Thanks in advance.
Salman ansari

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use SSIS? I believe you're asking about how to deploy database changes from development to production, and SSIS is not a good tool for that purpose; it's used for data integration and is not at all suitable for synchronizing schema or object changes.

I think you need to define your requirements a bit more clearly before you decide on a solution. For example, it's very unusual to upgrade a production database by using a complete copy of your development database, because you lose all the data in production. Perhaps your use case allows for this, though.

In any case, you need to focus on finding a deployment solution that works for your environment, e.g. [VS database projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833165%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or  a schema comparison tool such as [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/). After you've done some research, you may be able to ask more specific questions about the best solution for your particular case.